# Porting Dynamic form binding Play 2 sample app in Play 1

Tags: java, playframework, reverse-engineering, dynamic-forms

Following is the Play 2 app,
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/forms

Which portrays Dynamic form binding where form fields and sections are dynamically added and removed at client side.

It is a Play 2 sample application. I wanted to port it on Play 1 code base.

If anyone could port the same app in Play framework 1.x t will be a great help ! 
A GitHub share would be an awesome way to incrementally improve the ported app !

Idea is to learn best possible practice in Play 1 for such a use case.[image: dynamic-form-generation-play-controller-binding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [list binding](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#array) and appropriately named fields and some JavaScript.